# "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value to int" when trying to filter a table by date

Tags: c#, sql-server

I want to do a simple select from my database in ASP.NET in C#.
I have a `SqlDataSource` on my aspx page and I have a table named `Eventmsgs` with 3 columns - `id (int), Msg (Varchar(max)), date (Varchar(max))` which have the events for each day.

I want to select only the msg for today. This is my code:

```
    String date = System.DateTime.Now.Date.ToShortDateString();
    SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM EventMsgs WHERE Date="+date;
    DataView dv = (DataView)SqlDataSource1.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
```

But when I call the `Select` method, I'm getting the following error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '4/25/2014' to
>   data type int

But why does it want to convert it to `int`?

Comment: Why do you have `Date` as `varchar(max)`? That's what `datetime` or `date` is for.

Comment: at first it was date but i couldn't find a way to use it in my where clause.see the answer's comment.thank you

Comment: I've added my own answer to explain what's happening and what you are doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try by wrapping the `date` value in single quotes(`'4/25/2014'`) like this:

```
SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand 
  = String.Format("SELECT * FROM EventMsgs WHERE Date='{0}'",date);
```

Comment: thank you it worked.and why is that?.and another question if i define my date column as Date datatype how can i use it in my where clause?

Comment: @user3003613 that is because, the `date` is a `varchar`. SQL will understand anything as a `varchar` only if it is inside single quotes (like '4/25/2014'). Otherwise, if it not in single quotes, it will do an intelligent thing to identify what it is. Since the `date` is starts with `integer`, it will try to convert it to `integer` value and fails.

Comment: @user3003613 If you are willing to compare with datatype as `Date` then it depends on how you are comparing the value. If you want to compare as above, you need to use single quotes. Or if you are storing Date value inside `SQL Variable (@var_name)`, then it is not necessary to use single quotes.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you compare two values of a different type in SQL, the server has to convert one of them first. So what's the two types you're comparing?

On the left-hand side, your `Date` column is of type `varchar(max)`, obviously. On the right hand side, however, you've got e.g. the value `4/25/2014` - which is four, divided by 25, divided by 2014 - an `int` with a value of `0`.

So when the server tries to do the comparison, it attempts to convert the left-hand side (the string) to an integer - but is unable to do so, because it's not an integer.

Your problem is that string literals have to be quoted, and the same thing applies to e.g. dates. If you used a different date format or any other string, you'd have gotten a syntax error instead, which would make the error clearer - as it is, the US format is actually a parseable expression (although it will always result in `0`). So to make this work, you have to use quotes around text / date values - for example, `'4/25/2014'`.

In any case, what you're doing is wrong on many levels:

- You shouldn't be using a `varchar` column to store a date. Much less `varchar(max)`. That's what `datetime` and `date` are for - use the correct data type. This is important for many reasons - you'll get the correct ordering, comparisons, and you'll have support by the date functions (`dateadd`, `datepart`, ...). Not to mention that it saves a bit of space. And you're saving a date value, which also means that if you pass something that isn't a valid date, you'll get chewed out on inserting, rather than when working with the incorrect data later - it's much easier to find errors as soon as possible.
- You shouldn't be passing values into SQL queries like this. Instead, you should always use parameters - `select * from EventMsgs where Date = @Date;`. You just add the parameter as the original `DateTime` value, and .NET (and SQL server) will handle the passing on its own, avoiding SQL injection openings and many other issues (for example, you'd get very "funny" errors if you were talking with an SQL server that interprets the date as `dd/MM/yyy` rather than `MM/dd/yyyy`).
- Usually, you wouldn't want to do custom SQL queries unless needed. Why not use an ORM like EntityFramework or LINQ2SQL to ease your work?

The sample code for the proper way of passing parameters would look something like this:

```
SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "select * from [EventMsgs] where [Date] = @Date;";
SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add("@Date", DateTime.Today);
```

Comment: thank you for your complete answer.and about the last part i'm going to use a lot of custom queries for user&pass verifying and other,are EntityFramework will work in these matters ?

Comment: and also i changed my column type to date and used your code instead but i'm getting :The best overloaded method match for 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ParameterCollection.Add(string, string)' has some invalid argument

Comment: @user3003613 Well, "custom queries" would mean "something the ORM doesn't support outright". User and password doesn't really count (it would mean e.g. `var user = Users.Where(u => u.UserName = userName && u.PasswordHash = passwordHash).SingleOrDefault();`

Comment: @user3003613 Oh, I assumed those are standard data provider parameters. ASP.NET's `SqlDataSource` is rather crazy. Well, try doing `DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString`, I assume it works with the server's locale settings. You *are* working with somewhat outdated technologies here :)

Comment: got it.so i'm going to transfer my data to a new database to work with EF.thank you for your answers.